# X-Editable Huge Checklist

Tags: javascript, css, forms, checkbox, x-editable

Im having a small problem with x-editable: I am loading a MySQL table via Ajax into a JavaScript Array and then I'm using this array as a source for my xeditable checklist input, everything works fine so far but I'm having an issue with displaying this "huge" list of data (31 Elements) and I want to ask if there is a way to split this checklist in half?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrUtk.png

I hope someone can think of a solution for this problem...

Best Regards: Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution for this problem (If anyone encounters the same problem, this may be helpful):

X-editable wraps the Checklists in a DIV with the class: `.editable-checklist` you can then apply CSS to that DIV:

`max-height: 500px;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;`

This solves the problem!